# How to Start Activity after Successful Signup using email and password on Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication, start-activity

I'm asking this Question After Reading Official Docs.
I managed to register user on my Firebase Authentication System but I want to start an Activity after successful Signup

here is my code

```
public class SignUpActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

FirebaseAuth mAuth;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_sign_up);
    mAuth=FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
}

public void fgh(View view) {
    mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword("example@email.com","password")
            .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                    if(task.isSuccessful())
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(SignUpActivity.this, "Successfully created your account", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        Intent intent = new Intent(this,SuccessActivity.class);  //this is my error
                        startActivity(intent);  // how to start activity here
                    }
                    else{
                        Toast.makeText(SignUpActivity.this, "ERROR has occurred", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }
            });
    }
}
```

[IDE Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XDbhs.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

get the context right so let it be
`Intent intent = new Intent(SignUpActivity.this,SuccessActivity.class);`

Comment: anyway ill try it again

Comment: it should work Activity instance is tied to the life cycle of an Activity

Answer (score 0):

To solve this, please change `this` that you are passing as the first argument with a method call like this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SuccessActivity.class);
```

There is another approach in which you can declare a global variable:

```
private Context context;
```

And initialize it in your `onCreate()` method like this:

```
context = this;
```

And then use it anywhere is needed in your activity.

Comment: Getting application context within an Activity doesn't seem like the greatest solution for the given problem. Activity context should be used